# parse dates in portuguese

Tags: r, lubridate

I have some dates in Portuguese that I'd like to parse.

```
dts = c('19-mai-17', '26-mai-17', '2-jun-17',  '9-jun-17',  '16-jun-17')
lubridate::parse_date_time(dts, orders = "d-b-y", locale = "pt-BR")
```

But it only returns the dates it overlaps with English while throwing some warnings:

```
[1] NA               NA               "2017-06-02 UTC" "2017-06-09 UTC" "2017-06-16 UTC"
Warning messages:
1: In Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", locale) :
  OS reports request to set locale to "pt-BR" cannot be honored
2: In Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", locale) :
  OS reports request to set locale to "pt-BR" cannot be honored
3: In Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", locale) :
  OS reports request to set locale to "pt-BR" cannot be honored
4:  2 failed to parse.
```

I got the `locale` code from: https://web.archive.org/web/20161105200145/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx

Running windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might only be a question of using the correct locale code. On MacOS `pt_BR` works fine for me. It turned out that on Windows you might want to try `Portuguese_Brazil.1252`. In any case, changing the `LC_TIME` locale per session is done by using

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_TIME", locale = "pt_BR")
```

Comment: thanks.how would I reset it to default after running this?

Comment: Well, restart your R session or use the same command but with your default locale.

Comment: actually running the code i have in the question and changing the `locale` argument to what you suggested (`Portuguese_Brazil.1252`) worked as well

Comment: Glad to hear. I'll edit the question a bit to account for that.

Comment: The trick here is just using an underscore, not a hyphen. You can use `"pt_BR"` (or similar) in `parse_date_time` and it should work fine.

Comment: If you want to reset the locale, before running the code above, run `old_loc <- Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_TIME")`, then, when done, reset it to `old_loc`.